# Chart.js 2.x - How to get handle of only clicked datapoint?

Tags: onclick, chart.js, datapoint

I have a multiline chart drawn using chart.js. I want to get **borderColor of the clicked point(datapoint) only**, when the user clicks on a particular point.

For understanding, I have two lines in my multi-line chart called `Prime and Fibonacci` and `My Second dataset` drawn using dataset `[12, 13, 15, 17, 111, 113, 117, 9, 3, 0]` and `[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 13, 21, 34]` respectively, both lines have a different borderColor `green` and `red` respectively.

Now, I want to catch only clicked point's `borderColor` when the user clicks on the datapoints. For example, when the user clicks on datapoint `111` which is from line `Prime and Fibonacci` then I should get borderColor as `green`, similarly when the user clicks on datapoint `11` from `My Second dataset` line, then I should get border color as red.

I have tried using below but **it gives me both colors doesn't matter on which lines data point the user clicked**.

```
var activePoints = lineChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
// Below code always gives me green and red, doesn't matter which line's data point the user clicked
activePoints[0]._chart.config.data.datasets[0].borderColor // Always gives green 
activePoints[0]._chart.config.data.datasets[1].borderColor // Always gives red
```

How can I do that? For quick setup take help of [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tocumom/edit?html,js,output).

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long struggle and research, I came up with below solution.

It will give me `_datasetIndex` which is helpful to understand the click event triggered from `Prime and Fibonacci` or `My Second dataset` line. If `activePoints[0]._datasetIndex` is `0` then it's from `Prime and Fibonacci`, similarly if `activePoints[0]._datasetIndex` is `1` then it's from `My Second dataset`.

```
ctx.onclick = function(evt) {
    var activePoints = lineChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);

    if (activePoints.length) {
      var mouse_position = Chart.helpers.getRelativePosition(evt, lineChart.chart);

      activePoints = $.grep(activePoints, function(activePoint, index) {
        var leftX = activePoint._model.x - 5,
            rightX = activePoint._model.x + 5,
            topY = activePoint._model.y + 5,
            bottomY = activePoint._model.y - 5;

        return mouse_position.x >= leftX && mouse_position.x <=rightX && mouse_position.y >= bottomY && mouse_position.y <= topY;
      });
      console.log(activePoints[0]._datasetIndex);
    }    
};
```

That said, here is working example [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tocumom/edit?html,js,output). I believe this is going to help many people who is having same scenario/problem.